# Unit -.mount is masked

Tags: systemd, services

I have this message while running `apt update`

```
Unit -.mount is masked.
```

I don't see any file or link to a service like `-.mount.service` in `/etc/systemd/system` or `/etc/systemd/user` or `~/.config/systemd/user` or under the `/lib/systemd` directories.

There is nothing like it in the output of `systemctl list units` or `systemctl --user list-units`

So where is this unit file? OR What is this message about?

Comment: Have look at this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/548996/157411

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error message.

Command: `sudo apt-get update`
Result: `Fehler: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked: Unit -.mount is masked.`

Solution:
I closed the program `gparted`